# Nodejs error message keeps popping up for registration system

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling

So I'm new to NodeJS and JS and am trying to create a registration system. I am trying to handle my error messages. Right now, every time I click register after filling out all the fields properly, I get the following output as seen in the image. However, I'm not sure why as I am inputting a full name as well as 2000-11-11 into the date of birth field, so I shouldn't be getting those error messages based on my code.

```
  router.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
  var name = req.body.name; 
  var email = req.body.email;
  var password = req.body.password; 
  var password2 = req.body.password2; 
  var bday = req.body.bday; 
  var birthday = moment(bday); 
  let errors = []; 

  // Form Validator
  if (!req.body.name) {
    errors.push({ msg: 'Please fill in all required fields' }); 
  }

  if (req.body.email && !req.body.email.isEmail()) {
    errors.push({ msg: 'Please provide an appropriate email' }); 
  }  

  if (req.body.password2 && req.body.password && req.body.password2 != req.body.password) {
    errors.push({ msg: 'Please provide passwords and make sure they match' }); 
  }

  if (req.body.bday && !birthday.isValid()) {
    errors.push({ msg: 'Date of Birth must be in appropriate format' }); 
  }

  if (moment().diff(birthday, 'years') < 13) {
    errors.push({ msg: 'User must be at least 13 years of age' }); 
  }

  if(errors.length > 0){
    res.render('register', {
      errors, 
      name, 
      email, 
      password, 
      password2, 
      bday
    });
  } else{
    var newUser = new User({
      name: name,
      email: email,
      password: password,
      bday: bday, 
    });
```

Error message:

[image]

Comment: what is the code that actually populates the request? What happens if you dump request.body, is name even in it?

Comment: can you log out `moment().diff(birthday, 'years') < 13`?